# Notepad++ move first two characters to end of line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list of Country Codes in the following format:

`US:United States`

I'm trying to replace it with

`United States:US`

I've moved the semi-colon to the end by searching for `^(.*)\b:\b(.*)$` and replacing with `\1\2:` but now need to move the first two characters to the end, or rerun the whole thing with one regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+):(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2:$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character
:           # colon
(.+)        # group 2, 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2      # content of group 2
:       # colon
$1      # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]